# Width of container fluid not changing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a table like this(m using bootstrap):

```
div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:220px;">
<div class="allresults span7" id="result" style="position: relative; top:-57px">  
</div>  
</div>
```

content of results i am setting in javacript file

The problem I a facing is the table width is very less. it has 7 columns, but it appears in the center of the page in very less ares , less width.
How should i change the width of table, 
because like this all columns appear very contracted.

Comment: you have not opened < in first div and also where did you define the width?

Answer (score 1):

you write open < triangular ahead of first div and run code.

> `<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:220px;">`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. It should have been `span12`, not `span 7`